# Adding additional variables to Subject Line in form

Tags: php, forms

I didn't write this code, but I would like to be able to add the first name of my form to the subject line as well as a random variable.  The code I got from 
[HTML-FORM-GUIDE.com](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/contact-form-attachment.html) as I don't know code beyond basic html.  I would also like to have a CC go to the sender.  I am not sure if you needed more code than what I have pasted.  I wasn't sure how to add the variables $this->first_name as well as rand(11,999) and get them to show up in the subject line.

Form area:

```
<label for='first_name' >First Name*: </label>
<input type='text' name='first_name' id='first_name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('first_name') ?>' maxlength="60" />    <br/>
<span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
```

PHP Code area (Goal is to have subject read as Request from First, Name & random code)

```
     function SendFormSubmission()
{
    $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();
    $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';    
    $this->mailer->Subject = "Request from $this->name" ;
```

For Email the recipient code looks like this:

```
$formproc->AddRecipient('me@myemail.com');
```

Form field:

```
<label for='email' >Email*:</label></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="60" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
 function SendFormSubmission(){
    $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();
    $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';  
    // Concat string with random number   
    $this->mailer->Subject = "Request from $this->name"." with random number :".rand(11,999) ;
    // Add CC
    $this->mailer->AddCC($senderEmail);
    .
    .
    .
```